# Save random_bytes-generated key in database using Doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine

I am trying to generate a relatively secure key and store it in the database. I am using PHP Symfony and Doctrine to manage my MySQL-Database. Here is my code:

```
$account->setVk(random_bytes(32));
$entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$entityManager->persist($account);
$entityManager->flush();
```

I always get the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect string value: '\xB7\xC3!\xEC\xE0\xCD...'
```

Just using a normal String like '12345' works well. Vk is a column of type String with the length of 255. Why is the String weirdly formatted like that and why wont Doctrine not accept the String generated by random_bytes? (Although I think the error is more on the MySQL side of things)

Comment: Either encode the key in some string-safe encoding [eg: hex or base64] or change the column type to its binary equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

You are triying to save a random string (random_bytes) in a property defined in database as DateTime type.

Go to account entity and check the $vk property. You should change ORM/Column to strig if you really need to save a random string.